# Contextual filter is not working

Tags: views

I have **views1** and **view2**, where in first view linked with view2 so I have given contextual filter in view both for entity reference field of view2.

Now my problem is when I pass nid of view1 at Preview with contextual filters: it not retaining any data the contextual filter is not working.
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you be more descriptive or add some screenshots ?

Comment: @HimanshuPathak: yes i can do that

Comment: check in the first screen that i have added the contextual field where in its entity reference field and inter linked with another view1 whenever we passing the node it not filtering

Comment: What I can understand is, you have a content type with field entity reference for other nodes. In the content node you want to show a view of related nodes provided in entity reference field. Right ?

Comment: @Himanshu Pathak:yes

Comment: posted an answer, ask me if facing any difficulties

Comment: @HimanshuPathak: when i choose nid as contextual filter view is disappearing

Comment: @HimanshuPathak: where in View1 or view2 i need to give the contextual filter condition

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to place 1 contextual filter for nid and one relationship with referenced entity, and use that relationship in fields. 
See the attached screenshot of a demo view. [image]

Comment: :while selecting nid view is disappearing